# Automatic import of the lexicon for the Game of Life

Tags: import, game, demonstrations

I am trying to import the lexicon for the [Game of Life](https://playgameoflife.com), preserving the structured information as far as possible *automatically* (so if the data changes a future import will update it).

The text form of the lexicon is here:

`lexicon = Import["https://conwaylife.com/ref/lexicon/zip/lex_asc.zip", "lexicon.txt"]`

Apart from the introductory text, the format for each configuration is of the form

```
:1-2-3-4: (p4)  See also {Achim's p4}.
.....*.....
....*.*....
...*.*.*...
...*...*...
**.*.*.*.**
```

where the name is delimited by :...: and the starting configuration is a table of where `{. -> 0, * -> 1}`. So I'm after an `Association` of named configurations in a computable format.

My overall goal is to implement the full lexicon as a (graphical and/or text) `PopupMenu`, say in a Demonstration, that can be used to select the element and then play the game, something like the interface of [1](https://playgameoflife.com), only "better"...